# Pointer to a subarray of TypedArray

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, memory, typed-arrays

Imagine we have

```
var a = new Float64Array([1, 2, 3]),
    b = new Float64Array([4, 5]);

var c = new Float64Array(a.length + b.length);
```

Now I want to combine `a` and `b` into `c`. I have written a C++ BLAS binding to copy data between two double/single precision arrays. Thing is, this binding has no `offset` attribute:

```
void cblas_dcopy(int n, const double *x, const int inc_x, const double *y, const int inc_y);
```

Can I get a subarray pointing to an offset of `c`'s memory space? The following is called in JavaScript:

```
// copy first to result, works
cblas_dcopy(3, a, 1, c, 1);

// does not work because slice() returns a copy
cblas_dcopy(2, b, 1, c.slice(a.length), 1);

// now how would I copy to c at offset b.length?
```

Comment: Hey, the cblas_dcopy is a C++ binding called from javascript so don't remove the javascript tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this easily without a C++ binding:

```
var a = new Float64Array([1, 2, 3]);
var b = new Float64Array([4, 5]);
var c = new Float64Array(a.length + b.length);
c.set(a, 0);
c.set(b, a.length);
```

To get the subarray as you asked, try using [`typedarray.subarray([begin[, end]])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/subarray).